# How to run external war file with embedded tomcat of spring boot with gradle?

Tags: spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am trying to deploy external war file into embedded tomcat of spring boot.I added gradle dependencies in the format of .war file and i want run this war with by spring boot app , but not running please anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with this approach. add this code block in your spring boot application.
your war file must be placed in a `src/main/resources` directory.

```
@Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
        return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

            @Override
            protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(Tomcat tomcat) {

                new File(tomcat.getServer().getCatalinaBase(), "webapps").mkdirs();

                try {

                    tomcat.addWebapp("/cms", new ClassPathResource("cms.war").getFile().toString());

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to add webapp",ex);
                }
                return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
            }
        };

    }
```

-> change the base directory in the application.properties as

```
server.tomcat.basedir=temp-server
```

Answer (score 0):

A few classes have changed in Spring Boot 2 and hence you'll have to do:

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        protected TomcatWebServer getTomcatWebServer(Tomcat tomcat) {
            new File(tomcat.getServer().getCatalinaBase(), "webapps").mkdirs();
            try {
                tomcat.addWebapp("/cms", new ClassPathResource("cms.war").getFile().toString());

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to add webapp", ex);
            }
            return super.getTomcatWebServer(tomcat);
        }
    };
}
```