# Can Spring boot based application's embedded jetty/tomcat also run external war file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We are trying to evaluate following scenario (to support couple of legacy apps and new apps).

- Team has developed application based on spring boot and working OK (using embedded Jetty ie. typical spring boot JAR)
- We have couple of legacy small applications (Spring MVC/Apache Camel based) which were packaged as WAR .
- WARs can not be placed into " src/main/resources" (application is already packaged)

We know that in spring boot we can specify external lib directory from where JARs are scanned and initialised.

Is there any way where we can provide WAR file to this spring boot application as runtime argument and it gets exploded-initialised-served  (along side of spring boot app)

(This is not duplicate of [How to run external war file with embedded tomcat of spring boot with gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150868/how-to-run-external-war-file-with-embedded-tomcat-of-spring-boot-with-gradle) .. We are having different scenario)